# Mysql group by query removing the null entries

Tags: mysql

one of my query gives result in the following manner

```
ID COL1   COL2    
1  null   abc
1  xyz    null
```

i need the output in the following way without using self join

```
ID COL1 COL2

1   xyz  abc
```

Please help

Comment: *"without using self join"* - Why? And what if there are two rows that have a value in col2 and one (or maybe even none) that have a value in col1?

Comment: Just use GROUP BY with a MAX

Comment: would be potentially easier to assist if you provided the query

Comment: We can't see the query. We can't see the DDLs, and we're not allowed to use a standard SQL tool without explanation. I think I'm not going to bother with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT MAX(ID), MAX(COL1), MAX(COL2)
FROM TABLE1;
```